# Is it okay to use an HTTP DELETE to deactivate a record?

Tags: api, rest, put, http-delete

I'm building a RESTful API command to deactivate a user record. Is it kosher to use DELETE to do this or should this be a PUT, since the record is being updated to "deactivated" status? Or is it just a matter of taste?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The semantics of `DELETE` means that you are actually getting rid of the object. What you're doing here seems like a modification of the object's state. In this case a `PUT` or `PATCH` would be more appropriate.

It is better to stick with the semantics of uniform interface that you're using (in this case, HTTP verbs). If those match up to what you're actually doing within your app, then there is less confusion. Also, what if you decide later that a `DELETE` should actually remove a record instead of just marking it "inactive"? Now you've changed the behavior of your API. Also, if you're using `DELETE`, you're essentially following the "principle of least surprise", which is good for an API. It's better to have a `DELETE` actually do a delete, rather than just pretending to do so.

On the other hand it is perfectly fine to remove the record from one location and move it elsewhere (from one table to another, for example) if it turns out that you are required to keep the data for historical purposes. In this case, that record should just remain unavailable to future operations (i.e., a `GET` on the resource should return a `404`).

Comment: Just a small addition: According to [RFC-2616](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-9.7) the server may also move the resource to an inaccessible location. At the end a `GET` on the deleted resource should return a `404`

Comment: @prehfeldt Correct! I mentioned that in my last paragraph. Added the bit about the `404` for additional clarification.

Comment: Worth adding: If you use a soft-delete deletion technique, `DELETE` is still appropriate.

Comment: I agree with @ChristoKiwi. Many applications do not physically delete any record in database, but mark `IsDeleted` column (or similar) as `1`. So the whole history of state history is kept.

Answer (score 8):

If after your deactivation operation, the resource is not accessible to the end user any more through "GET" unless it is reactivated again, I do not see a problem using "DELETE". Otherwise, "PUT" is more appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

If the resource at the URL you send the `DELETE` request to is no longer available at that URI, then `DELETE` is appropriate. If it remains there but changes state, then it is not.

e.g. this is okay (the resource at /friends/bob goes away; a new resource is created at /formerfriends/bob in the process, but that is incidental):

```
GET /friends/bob => 200 OK
GET /formerfriends/bob => 404 Not Found
DELETE /friends/bob => 204 No Content
GET /friends/bob => 410 Gone
GET /formerfriends/bob => 200 OK
```

this is not:

```
GET /friends/bob => 200 OK {"status"="friend"}
DELETE /friends/bob => 204 No Content
GET /friends/bob => 200 OK {"status"="formerfriend"}
```

something like that would be better handled with `PUT` or `PATCH`:

```
GET /friends/bob => 200 OK {"status"="friend"}
PATCH /friends/bob {"status"="formerfriend"} => 204 No Content
GET /friends/bob => 200 OK {"status"="formerfriend"}
```