# REST verb for state change - can we agree on POST?

Tags: rest, rpc, fsm

How to best extend REST with FSM state changes?

No one can know if a state change is idempodent or not, so the wisest thing may be to assume they're not, and as a general rule use POST, ok?

To me and my findings, POST makes more sense than PUT or PATCH.

```
POST /coffeemachines/{id}/start
```

or maybe more verbose?

```
POST /coffeemachines/{id}/state/start
```

Although *start* looks like a verb (breaking REST-practices), I think it's not:

- The main verb is a poking POST, we want a state-change.
- start is just the attribute-value for the requested state-change.

I guess I'm not the first man on the moon here, thankful for any references or thoughts.

Comment: You may find this useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529315/hateoas-how-to-model-link-relations-that-change-state

Answer (score 2):

You can send a partial update request with HTTP PATCH that contains only the new state.

```
PATCH /coffeemachines/{id}
{
    status: "active"
}
```

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_verb):

> The PATCH method is a request method supported by the HTTP protocol for making partial changes to an existing resource. The PATCH method provides an entity containing a list of changes to be applied to the resource requested using the HTTP URI. The list of changes are supplied in the form of a PATCH document.

It is also more readable to separate words in the path with hyphens. For example:

```
PATCH /coffee-machines/{id}
{
    status: "active"
}
```

Comment: I've considered this too, but discarded patch for reasons I don't remember.. The state-change could be considered as something "new" as in POST /statechange but the PATCH-approach clearly makes more sense when in a resource-context.

Comment: @scokmen I have seen this suggestion in other places as well, and it makes sense because using actions in URIs is not considered REST. But REST API should be discoverable and implement HATEOAS. How can a consumer know what possible state changes are available? Also, letting the consumer to give you the name of the next state might be a security risk. If you have separate endpoints like OP mentioned, then you can list all available next states as HATEOAS links and make the API more discoverable. So in my mind, both options have trade offs and I have yet to find a fully RESTful solution to this

Answer (score 2):

> REST verb for state change - can we agree on POST?

The reference implementation of REST is the World Wide Web, which was catastrophically successful even though HTML (the dominant media type) only specified support for `GET` and `POST`.

Using `POST` for unsafe operations is *fine*.

> Although start looks like a verb (breaking REST-practices)

No -- REST doesn't care about the spellings of URI.  That's part of the point: the server can change the URI in links any time it likes because the clients just follow the links.

That said, there is an issue with your proposed identifiers, which you may want to consider

```
/coffeemachines/{id}
/coffeemachines/{id}/start
```

As far as REST is concerned, these are *different* resources.  That means that your locally cached copy of `/coffeemachines/{id}` is not [invalidated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) when you `POST` a request to `/coffeemachines/{id}/start`.

If you care to take advantage of the caching support that is already built into the domain agnostic components that are available, then you want the target of the `POST` to match the target of the `GET`: `/coffeemachines/{id}`

`/coffeemachines/{id}/start`, in this design, isn't the target of the `POST`, but is instead the identifier of the form resource that submits start messages to `/coffeemachines/{id}`.  Likewise, `/coffeemachines/{id}/stop` would identify the form resource that submits stop messages.

The representation of the coffee machine would include links to these forms when the transitions are permitted; for instance, when the coffee machine is off, then the representation of the coffee machine returned by `GET` would include a link to the start form, but not a link to the stop form.

`/coffeemachines/{id}/start` and `/coffeemachines/{id}/stop` are different resources from `/coffeemachines/{id}`, and therefore might have their own caching policies.

Of course, it isn't *required* that the forms be separate resources -- the mechanism would also work if the forms were part of the representation of the `/coffeemachines/{id}` resource itself.

> Can I ask you to elaborate around POST vs PATCH

I found that this [observation by Roy Fielding](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html) helped me:

> HTTP does not attempt to require the results of a GET to be safe.  What it does is require that the semantics of the operation be safe, and therefore it is a fault of the implementation, not the interface or the user of that interface, if anything happens as a result that causes loss of property

[PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) has stricter semantics than [POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3); that means that clients (and generic components) can make *stronger* assumptions about what is going on.

So in the following examples:

```
PATCH /foo HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

POST /foo HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json
```

The server can handle these messages in exactly the same way.  Clients that recognize the PATCH method will recognize that the unsafe changes on the server are supposed to be all-or-nothing ("The server MUST apply the entire set of changes atomically...") and can leverage that as they like, but with POST, that additional constraint is missing and cannot be assumed.

The PATCH spec notes:

> A comparison to POST is even more difficult, because POST is used in widely varying ways and can encompass PUT and PATCH-like operations if the server chooses.  If the operation does not modify the resource identified by the Request-URI in a predictable way, POST should be considered instead of PATCH or PUT.

Comment: Can I ask you to elaborate around POST vs PATCH because I'm still confused about any formal rules here. Example, https://apihandyman.io/do-you-really-know-why-you-prefer-rest-over-rpc/ both POST and PATCH fits for a state-change which makes no sense to me.

Comment: I don't believe that article by Arnaud Lauret is particularly effective.  If you already "get it", then you can find the right meanings in what he wrote.  If you don't, then I don't believe it helps at all.